# Gerrit and Gitblit bare repo setup

Tags: git, gerrit, gitblit

I'm in early stages of setting up Gerrit and realized I would need a copy of my "bare repo" hosted by gitblit. If I understand the documentation Gerrit also needs to have a bare repo.

I was wondering if it is a good idea to point Gerrit to the same repository (in installation gerrit asks for the local repo) as my Gitblit, they are both running on the same server on different ports. Or should I keep them seperate and have two bare repo's. One for gitblit and one for gerrit.

How does your setup look like? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit supports other tools making changes to the repository behind its back, so this should run fine unless Gitblit does any caching and could get confused by changes made by Gerrit.  I'd say give it a try - it is much better to have one repository rather than 2 that you must keep in sync.

Comment: I agree with @Brad.  This should be fine.